# Stop useEffect from running on mount

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

I only want useEffect to run when my dependency list changes, it is also running every time the component is mounted, is there any way to not fire on mount?

> You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values
>   haven’t changed between re-renders.

I initially thought that meant it shouldn't re-render on subsequent mounts but [this question cleared that up.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56195643/210757)

I am displaying a list of records in a master "page" (react-router), the user can choose a single record and go to the detail page, and then return to the master page - so the master list component is completely unmounted/mounted in that scenario.  And every time I load the "master page", I see the data being fetched, I only want this to happen when one of the dependencies changes; these dependencies and the data itself are stored in Redux so they're global.

Can useEffect or another hook be made to only fire when the dependencies change?

```
const {page, pageSize, search, sorts} = useSelector(getFilters);
const data = useSelector(getData);

useEffect(() => {

  console.log("fetching");
  dispatch(fetchData(page, pageSize, search, sorts));

}, [page, pageSize, search, sorts]);
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't configure it out of the box.

But, a common pattern is to use some `isMounted` flag like so:

```
// Is Mounted
const useFetchNotOnMount = () => {
  ...
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      console.log('fetching');
      dispatch(fetchData(filters));
    } else {
      isMounted.current = true;
    }
  }, [dispatch, filters]);
};

// Same (Is First Render)
const useFetchNotOnMount = () => {
  ...
  const isFirstRender = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRender.current) {
      isFirstRender.current = false;
    } else {
      console.log("fetching");
      dispatch(fetchData(filters));
    }
  }, [dispatch, filters]);
};
```

- Read more in depth [uses of `useEffect`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59841800/react-useeffect-in-depth-use-of-useeffect/59841947#59841947)

Comment: I believe there is a bug with the second example, the "Is First Render" one. Instead of `isFirstRender = false` it should be `isFirstRender.current = false`.

Comment: @GregL thanks you are right

Comment: The problem with this approach is that useEffect is called twice on mount when in dev mode. (I hate react!!!)

Answer (score 2):

If you have several `useEffect` to prevent from running at initially, you can do the following:

```
export default function App() {
  const mountedRef = useMountedRef();
  const [isLoggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);
  const [anotherOne, setAnotherOne] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mountedRef.current) {
      console.log("triggered", isLoggedIn);
    }
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mountedRef.current) {
      console.log("triggered", anotherOne);
    }
  }, [anotherOne]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (mountedRef.current) {
      console.log("triggered", isLoggedIn, anotherOne);
    }
  }, [anotherOne, isLoggedIn]);

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => setLoggedIn(true)}>Login</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const useMountedRef = () => {
  const mountedRef = React.useRef(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      mountedRef.current = true;
    });
  }, []);

  return mountedRef;
};
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-eelqp2

One thing important is that you have to use `setTimeout` to make a reasonable delay to make sure that the ref value is set to true after all initial useEffects.

Comment: I think this is bad, no matter how much time you give to `setTimeout`, you'll never be sure that's enough. 

The only true fix is to have an `useEffect` that is ALWAYS LAST (order is important!) and sets `mountedRef.current = true;`

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom hook to run use effect after mount.

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb, dependencies) => {
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      return cb();
    }
    mounted.current = false;
  }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
};

useEffectAfterMount(() => {

  console.log("fetching");
  dispatch(fetchData(page, pageSize, search, sorts));

}, [page, pageSize, search, sorts]);
```

Here is the `typescript` version:

```
const useEffectAfterMount = (cb: EffectCallback, dependencies: DependencyList | undefined) => {
  const mounted = useRef(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!mounted.current) {
      return cb();
    }
    mounted.current = false;
  }, dependencies); // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to the game but I think it's also worth noting that for what the OP is trying to accomplish, data caching would be a more wholistic and scalable solution. Libraries like [react-query](https://react-query-v3.tanstack.com/) are great for this.