# How do I fire React useEffect hook only once after state change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am new to React hooks and I am not sure how to achieve following goal. Let's say I have `state1` and `state2`, and I use `useEffect` hook to call `asyncFn1` and update `state1`.

Now I want to wait for `state1` change and use `state1` value to call `asyncFn2` and update both `state1` and `state2`. This `asnycFn1` and `asyncFn2` should only be called once.

If I just use another `useEffect` to call `asyncFn2`, I won't get the `state1` value. How do I solve that?

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState(null);
const [state2, setState2] = useState(null);

const asyncFn1 = async() => {
  // async call to get state 1 data
  // setState1
}

const asyncFn2 = async(_state1) => {
  // use state1 data to make async call to get state 2 data
  // state2 data will be used to update both state1 and state2
}

useEffect(() => {
  asyncFn1();
}, [])
```

Comment: Why do you want to update `state1` from `asyncFn2`? Does the input `_state1` to `asyncFn2` differ from the state you want to call `setState1` with?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492626/stop-useeffect-from-running-on-mount/59492738#59492738, same logic, have a ref which acts as "called once" flag.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes the state 1 will cause different asyncFn2 result which will be used to update the state1 again.

Comment: @DennisVash thank you! useRef is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need here is a useEffect which has your `state1` in the useEffect dependency array, so to trigger it any time your `state1` value changes, as such:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   state1 && asyncFn2()
}, [state1])
```

In case you want your `asyncFn2` to trigger only once after you get the data for state1, you can just add a ref to check when that's being called:

```js
const dataLoaded = useRef(false)

useEffect(() => {
   if(state1 && !dataLoaded.current) {
      asyncFn2()
   }
}, [state1])

const asyncFn2 = async () => {
   // Your logic here

   // Set dataLoaded on true once you have updated what you need successfully
   dataLoaded.current = true
}
```

Comment: I see you fixed your example, but my statement is not wrong, previously you called `useCallback` inside `useEffect`, try this code and tell me about your findings

Comment: also, it should be `!dataLoadedRef.current` instead `!dataLoadedRef` which is always a truthy statement

Comment: True, that's a good point thanks for pointing - but what you said about not using hooks inside functions, what are functional components then?

Comment: In React terms, there are "Function Components" and when saying "functions" those are just JS functions, see https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html "Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions"

Answer (score 0):

I do this quite often and found that for me the most readable (and understandable) method is to use a hook that stores the previous value of something.

```js
export function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}
```

Then when I want create a side effect only when one specific value in my state changes I write:

```js
const [fetching, setFetching] = useState(false);
const prevFetching = usePrevious(fetching);

useEffect(() => {
  if (prevFetching === true && fetching === false) {
    // Do something
  }
}, [fetching, prevFetching]);
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for the result of asyncFn1 to fetch the data for asyncFn2 you can use IIFE inside the useEffect and wait for asyncFn1 to complete executing and use the result to make the call to asyncFn2.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async function(){
      const result1 = await asyncFn1();
      // Use the result to fetch the data for asyncFn2 
      const result2 = await asyncFn2();
      // Update both state1 and state2
     })()
    }, [])
```