# React useEffect syntax reason on mount

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm following this tutorial

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/5-advanced-react-patterns-a6b7624267a6

Can you explain me what's the purpose of this code, please?

```
const firstMounded = useRef(true);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!firstMounded.current) {
      onChange && onChange(count);
    }
    firstMounded.current = false;
  }, [count, onChange]);
```

https://github.com/alex83130/advanced-react-patterns/blob/main/src/patterns/compound-component/Counter.js#L9

Comment: It's to call your `onChange()` function only when `count` is updated. Without the ref / condition, `onChange()` would be called upon mounting as well (see [Make React useEffect hook not run on initial render](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53253940))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59492626/stop-useeffect-from-running-on-mount/59492738#59492738

Answer (score 1):

useEffect is react renders after a component is mounted / rendered in the DOM . In your case , the useEffect will be triggered,

1. when the component is mounted for the first time
2. when the value of count changes
3. when the onChange changes ,